# Server process being killed on a Linux Digitalocean VM

Tags: node.js, next.js, server, digital-ocean

I am trying to run a Next.js server on a DigitalOcean virtual machine. The server works, but when I run `npm run start`, the logs say `Killed` after ~1 minute.

Here is an example log of what happens:

```
joey@mydroplet:~/Server$ sudo node server
info  - SWC minify release candidate enabled. https://nextjs.link/swcmin
event - compiled client and server successfully in 3.3s (196 modules)
wait  - compiling...
event - compiled client and server successfully in 410 ms (196 modules)
> Ready on https://localhost:443
> Ready on http://localhost:8080
wait  - compiling / (client and server)...
event - compiled client and server successfully in 1173 ms (261 modules)
Killed
joey@mydroplet:~/Server$
```

After some research, I came across a couple of threads which detail a server lacking enough memory/resources to continue the operation. I upgraded the memory from 512 mb to 1 gb, but this still happens.

Do I need to further upgrade the memory?
This is the plan that I am on:

[image: Image of digitalocean plan]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was the memory. Upgrading the memory of the server from 1 gb to 2 gb solved this problem.

This is the plan that worked for me:

[image: Working plan]